# Appcelerator build fails when using Appcelerator Studio

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I'm having an issue when trying to compile and run an app through Appcelerator Studio. The error I get is pretty non descriptive:

FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.

I gather it has something to with the v8 engine but the weird thing is the build goes fine through the CLI. This wouldn't be much of an issue if liveview wasn't tied with Studio.

Here's my system information:

```
Operating System
Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version                     = 10.0.14393
Architecture                = 64bit
# CPUs                      = 8
Memory                      = 8229597184

Node.js
Node.js Version             = 6.9.5
npm Version                 = 3.10.10
Titanium CLI
CLI Version                 = 5.0.11

Titanium SDK
SDK Version                 = 6.0.2.GA
SDK Path                    =       C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.2.GA
Target Platform             = android
```

Comment: try using CLI for LiveView http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Command-Line_Interface_Reference

Comment: Have you tried disabling LiveView on the Studio. Its the icon next to your device dropdown list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use node version 4.6.x? Here is the link:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Node.js

Comment: This did the trick. Weird, I kinda ruled it out before because I remembered Studio's installer saying it was happy with my node version. But now that I think about it, maybe it was npm. Anyway, thanks!